# css style fieldset

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

i'm new to css  and i'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate a legend tag as an 
header for my page

currently my master page is styled by a field set :

```
 fieldset.field_set_main
 {
     border-bottom-width:50px;
     border-top-width:100px;
     border-left-width:30px;
     border-right-width:30px;       
     margin:auto;    
     width:1300px;
     height:700px;
     padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
     border-color:Black;    
     border-style:outset;  
     display:table;
}

legend.header
{          
     text-align:right;
}

<fieldset class="field_set_main" >
    <legend class="header">
        buy for you 
    </legend>                              
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                                                                                  
</fieldset>
```

1. The legend caption appears with its own background color "white" , if i set it to black 
   only the caption text itself "buy for you" get's black , it appears as a white box in   the  right of my border, Ii'm looking for a css style for the legend to appear as an header for the page
   ( with the same background color as the fieldset's background color , a different forecolor for the text ).
2. Is there a footer element in the fieldset , i want  a caption to appear at the bottom of the page as well.
3. Any good sources for useful css styles ? especially for master pages styled with a main fieldset ?

Comment: Visit the W3Schools website and read up on css, usually color sets the text color and background sets the background color. It's all very logical when you learn the different names. Also, just targeting the class is enough, but up to u.

Comment: iv'e  been there w3s give's the simplest examples 
still i can't figure out  how to place it as if it was a caption inside the border .
i know that color is the fore-color but it add no affect 
i even tried making the background transparent but nothing helped .
thanks any ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use `fieldset` as a container for your entire page, and `legend` as a page header. This is a misuse of the semantics of those two elements.

If you need elements to wrap the page for styling, I highly recommend you change your markup and CSS to:

```
 .field_set_main {
     border: 30px solid black;
     border-bottom-width:50px;
     border-top-width:100px;
     margin:auto;    
     width:1300px;
     height:700px;
     padding: 0;
     display:table;
}

.header
{          
     text-align:right;
}

<div class="field_set_main" >
    <h1 class="header">
        buy for you 
    </h1>                              
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                                                                                  
</div>
```

The `legend` field is notoriously hard to style consistently and completely, so I'd avoid its use unless it's semantically vital, which in your case it sounds like that's definitely not the case.

Comment: thanks .
it's just some post i came about suggesting that 
i have 0 idea how to style .
though the problem still stands :

how do i make my header be inside the page top border ,
hod do i incorporate a caption to my bottom border. 
??